# Python script to tail a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to tail a log file on a remote server using a Python script. The log file rolls over very fast, I am using the python-sshtail module to tail the log file and capture the output of the tail in a file on my local machine. I was able to capture the log file and save it to a file on my local machine but the my script seems to be writing it twice and data is formatted. 
           The script is working but not the way I want it to, I should be able to run the script, perform some actions on the servers, tail the logs, save the output to a file on my local machine and kill the script using CTRL-C.

I did write some code and it does work but not the way it should. For now I am using time.sleep to wait for the output to be written to the output file on my local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import sshtail.tailers as t
import sys
import datetime

username = "username"

logfile = "/var/log/file.log"

k = t.paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('keyfile')

conn = t.SSHTailer(username,logfile, k, verbose=True)

try:

    conn.connect()
    print(f"Connected to {conn.host}")
    print("Tailing the file..")

except:

    print("Connection unsuccesful...")

conn.tail()


for line in conn.tail():
    print(line)

for line in conn.get_new_lines():
    print(line)

x = conn.remote_file_size

print(f"The file size is: {x}")

time.sleep(10)

output_file = str(conn.host)+"_"+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"))+".txt"

with open(output_file, "a") as f:

    for line in conn.get_new_lines():
        print(line)
        f.write(line)

conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: The python-sshtail module can be found at this link
https://pypi.org/project/python-sshtail/

Comment: What modifications do I need to make to the script in order to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend replacing `time.sleep` with `asyncio.sleep`